# VSTO button getVisible call back not calling

Tags: vsto

I'm new to VSTO development and  need to hide and show a button .

```
<button id="buttonSlide" label="Content" size="large"  getVisible="SetStaticVisible"/>
```

> private string SetStaticVisible(IRibbonControl control)    {
>
> ```
>       return "true"    }
> ```

but this is not working and I have put a anothercall back to disable tab (where button is available)and that is working fine

what will be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a special reason why you return the boolean value as a string? I think this might be the problem. Also, try using a public method, tough I'm not sure if this is required. Try:

```
public bool SetStaticVisible(IRibbonControl control) 
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked. my bad to use return string instead of bool value.